# How to execute scala code using java

Tags: java, scala

I am new to `scala`. I have a requirement to execute the scala class using java.

My exact requirement is: I need to pass the entire scala class (file) as an argument to the java `jar`. That `jar` should read the `scala` code and execute it. I have searched many sites but did not find the appropriate answer. Is there any way to do the same?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Uh, but... why?

Comment: Actually we are developing an application. In that we got this requirement.

Comment: I would say explain it further, is this a homework assignment? What would this accomplish for you? Are you attempting to do some form of plugins/extensibility? Reading scala into the same environment and executing scala (from java) into it's own process are two entirely different worlds as well.

Answer (score 3):

Besides of your motivation to do that, it is for sure possible (I did it using my IDE - sbt project)
I just made scala class as below:

```
import com.google.common.base.Objects

class Car(_color: String, _valid: Boolean) {
  val color: String = _color
  val valid: Boolean = _valid

  override def toString = Objects.toStringHelper(this).add("color",color).add("valid", valid).toString
}
```

After that I made class with `main` method to test it.

```
public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car test = new Car("test", true);
        System.out.println("test = " + test);
    }
}
```

It compiled without any problems and the result was like below:

```
test = Car{color=test, valid=true}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala has its own compiler `scalac` whereas java uses `javac`. Since `scalac` compiles to class file that java can read and assuming that you are only using java libraries in the class then you can load the class in java. So what you need is to call scalac to compile the scala file and then load the generate class file using ClassLoader